# how to apply regex for m/dd/yyyy

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column consisting of string which contain date and time. the date is in the format of : mm/dd/yyyy , m/d/yyyy, m/dd/yyyy and mm/d/yyyy
i used regex which helps me extract mm/dd/yyyy and m/d/yyyy.
I am unable to extract m/dd/yyyy and mm/d/yyyy

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('path of csv file')
corpus = []
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    x = df.iloc[i]['OrderTime']
    if re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}',x):  ### for mm/dd/yyyy
        y= re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}',x)
        corpus.append(y)
    elif re.search(r'\d{1}/\d{1}/\d{4}',x): ### for m/d/yyyy
        y= re.findall(r'\d{1}/\d{1}/\d{4}',x)
        corpus.append(y)
    elif re.search(r'\d{1}/\d{2}\d{4}',x): ### for m/dd/yyyy
        y= re.findall(r'\d{1}/\d{2}/\d{4}',x)
        corpus.append(y)
    elif re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{1}\d{4}',x): ### for mm/d/yyyy
        y= re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{1}/\d{4}',x)
        corpus.append(y)
    else:                     ### empty cells or says nan
        y=["00/00/0000"]
        corpus.append(y)

print(corpus)
```

for eg - the date is 12/1/2017 the output is 2/1/2017 (issue with mm/d/yyyy)
         for date like 1/10/2018 output is 00/00/0000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.split` and `str.zfill` and `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['12/1/2017', '2/1/2017'], columns=['OrderTime'])
df1[['a','b','c']] = df.OrderTime.str.split('/',expand=True)
df['OrderTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.a.str.zfill(2)+'/'+df1.b.str.zfill(2)+'/'+df1.c)

print(df['OrderTime'])

0   2017-12-01
1   2017-02-01
Name: OrderTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If the format need to be in `'%m/%d/%Y'` use strftime, but this changes the datatype to object.

```
df.OrderTime.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
0    12/01/2017
1    02/01/2017
Name: OrderTime, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for those results is that you should change the order of the regexes and put the most specific ones first. Your regex does not use an anchor or a word boundary, so [`\d{1}/\d{1}/\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/FhueX5/1/) will match `2/1/2017` in `12/1/2017`.

Note that `\d{1}` can be written as `\d`

I think your code can be written easier, but for your current approach you could try it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('path of csv file')
corpus = []
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    x = df.iloc[i]['OrderTime']
    if re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}',x):  ### for mm/dd/yyyy
        y= re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}',x)
        corpus.append(y)
    elif re.search(r'\d{2}/\d/\d{4}',x): ### for mm/d/yyyy
        y= re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d/\d{4}',x)
        corpus.append(y)
    elif re.search(r'\d/\d{2}/\d{4}',x): ### for m/dd/yyyy
        y= re.findall(r'\d/\d{2}/\d{4}',x)
        corpus.append(y)
    elif re.search(r'\d/\d/\d{4}',x): ### for m/d/yyyy
        y= re.findall(r'\d/\d/\d{4}',x)
        corpus.append(y)
    else:                     ### empty cells or says nan
        y=["00/00/0000"]
        corpus.append(y)

print(corpus)
```

[Python test](https://ideone.com/UX5lJ8#stdin)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that "repetition count" can be a range rather than a single number?

```
re.findall(r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\d{4}',x)
               ^^^^^   ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using [pandas built-in date parser](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) when reading in the csv file? `pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates='OrderTime')`